# Groovy getSAMMethodImpl() Method Performance

Tags: groovy

I'm running a profiler against a running Java service (Spring Boot framework), containing multiple Groovy files all with the `@CompileStatic` annotation.

Now one of the most time consuming methods is an internal Groovy method (`getSAMMethodImpl()`).  I've been unsuccessful tracking down what this method is actually doing under the covers.

What exactly does this method do, and is there any way to prevent it from being called?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This method gets executed when a [`CachedClass`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/gapi/org/codehaus/groovy/reflection/CachedClass.html) for a class with a single abstract method (aka SAM) is created. Cached classes are Groovy mechanism to deal with a reflection in a more effective way - instead of always retrospecting classes from the beginning at the runtime it remembers e.g. modifications applied with metaprogramming (adding new methods to classes for instance), so it gets all class information very quickly. Of course it comes with some overhead.

For instance, when the meta class registry is initialized (once), it registers about 1180 methods. About 190 of them cause `CachedSAMClass.getSAMMethodImpl(Class<?> c)` to be executed. It happens, because [`ClassInfo.isSAM(Class<?> c)`](https://github.com/apache/groovy/blob/GROOVY_2_4_X/src/main/org/codehaus/groovy/reflection/ClassInfo.java#L404-L406) which checks if given class is a single abstract method class calls this method. And if you take a look at [`ClassInfo.createCachedClass(Class klazz, ClassInfo classInfo)`](https://github.com/apache/groovy/blob/GROOVY_2_4_X/src/main/org/codehaus/groovy/reflection/ClassInfo.java#L352-L402) you will see that this `isSAM()` method gets called always as a last check.

In most cases creating a registry of cached classes shouldn't be a problem - it happens one time for each class. Most of them get registered when you simply access `metaClass` property of any class. Or when you create a first closure. When it comes to performance, many different factors matter. For instance, Spring Boot uses hot swapping to reload classes at the runtime. In this case Groovy meta class registry gets recreated and all cached classes have to be recreated as well. The same thing may happen when you run a Spring Boot application with `spring-boot-devtools` dependency added - it uses additional class loader called [`RestartClassLoader`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/devtools/restart/classloader/RestartClassLoader.html) which requires additional meta class registry to be initialized. Actually the number of class loaders you have, that number of times meta class registry will be initialized (once for each class loader). This `RestartClassLoader` also causes recreating cached classes when it restarts.

And last but not least - if you want to measure performance correctly, try doing it on a production server instead of a local dev environment. If you can attach a debugger to the running process on a server and put a breakpoint in [`CachedSAMClass.getSAMMethodImpl(Class<?> c)` at line 169](https://github.com/apache/groovy/blob/GROOVY_2_4_X/src/main/org/codehaus/groovy/reflection/stdclasses/CachedSAMClass.java#L169), you can see how many times and for what classes this method gets executed. If it happens that it gets executed multiple times for the same class, it may suggest that your application is restarting class loader and Groovy has to rebuild meta class registry. It shouldn't happen - production application once started should not make any changes to class loader without a purpose. It is acceptable on a local dev - devtools and hot swapping will force meta class registry to be recreated any time class loader gets refreshed.